# Survey Enum in c#

Tags: c#, enums

```
public enum RoleType
{
    Supervisor,
    Administrator,
    User,
    UserPhone,
    Operator
}
```

I have an enum in my project and I'm going to compare a variable with these enum items!

How can I compare a variable with these items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i get what you are asking. You are looking for a way to iterate trough the enum values. You can do this using Enum.GetValues() that returns the int representation of the enum value.

```
foreach (int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RoleType)))
{
    //you can get the enum by casting the int to the enum type
    RoleType rtEnum = (RoleType)i;
}
```

Comment: If this code worked for you, please mark it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

or use a switch statement:

```
        switch(item)
        {
            case RoleType.Supervisor:
                break;
            case RoleType.Administrator:
                break;
            case RoleType.User:
                break;
            case RoleType.UserPhone:
                break;
            case RoleType.Operator:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
if(item == RoleType.Supervisor)
{
}
else if(item == RoleType.Administrator)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: with this solution I have to compare each item in enum with my variable! suppose items in enum are much and its better use foreach or lambda expression! but i dont know how can i take foreach for enum type in c#

Answer (score 0):

If the values are not mutually exclusive (i.e. a user can be in more than one role) you can decorate the enumeration with the `Flags` attribute and perform bitwise operations against it using operators or the `HasFlag()` method.

```
[Flags]
public enum RoleType
{
    Supervisor = 1,
    Administrator = 2,
    User = 4,
    UserPhone = 8,
    Operator = 16
}

// assume there is a user class with a collection of roles which have role types
var roles = (RoleType)user.Roles.Sum( o => o.RoleType );
if( roles.HasFlag( RoleType.User ) ){
    // do something
}
```